# How to use @keyframes for cross-fade gallery of images in css?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, keyframe, cross-fade

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akqno8L1/5/embedded/result) **(Fiddle A)** in which cross-fade gallery of images happen for 2 images (2 tiles). Here is the snippets of html/css which I have used.

```
<div class="featured-block" style="display:flex; justify-content: center;">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="https://i.imgur.com/EUqZ1Er.png" data-fallback-img="https://i.imgur.com/EUqZ1Er.png" alt="Outburst">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here are the @keyframes which I have used 2 images (2 tiles) for the above html:

```
@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    33% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    53% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

The above css-animation in **Fiddle A** is working perfectly fine(**which is exactly what I want**) when there are **2 tiles (2 images)**.

**Problem Statement:**

The above fiddle (Fiddle A) is working perfectly fine for 2 images. I want the same **css-animation/cross-fade gallery of images** happens when there **3 and 4 images**.

Here is the fiddle for 4 images(4 tiles) https://jsfiddle.net/zwjt8qko/1/embedded/result (Fiddle B)

Here is the fiddle for 3 images(3 tiles) https://jsfiddle.net/f6gr7kL1/embedded/result (Fiddle C)

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **keyframes in the Fiddle B (4 images) and Fiddle C (3 images)** above so that the same **css-animation/cross-fade** happens which is happening in **Fiddle A** right now.

I am open to a JavaScript solution as well.

Comment: Are you open to a JavaScript solution here? The easiest method would be to use JavaScript to toggle some class that would fade an image in and have all the others either already invisible or fading out as they lose that class. A pure CSS solution is possible but would be more complicated: you would likely need multiple different `@keyframes` animations all synced up.

Comment: @cjl750  Yes I am open for JS solution but I want to it to work like **Fiddle A (which has 2 images)**. I want the same thing to happen for **3 images (Fiddle C)** and **4 images (Fiddle B)** as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript method

Basic approach:

1. In your CSS, all pictures default to `opacity: 0`.
2. In your HTML, set a class name on one of the pictures that changes that picture's opacity to `1`.
3. In JavaScript, periodically toggle that class throughout the pictures.
4. Don't even bother with keyframes and just do our delaying in JavaScript directly. This lets you more easily modify how long you want different parts of the pulsing animation to last instead of having to calculate the percentage of the total `animation-duration` like you'd have to with keyframes.

```js
const pics = document.querySelectorAll('.pic');
const lastPic = pics.length - 1;
const transitionDuration = 800; // matches CSS
const transitionDelay = 3000; // up to you
const totalDelay = transitionDuration + transitionDelay;
const intervalDelay = (transitionDuration * 2) + transitionDelay; // time to fade out + time to fade in + time to stay active

function toggleClass() {
  const activePic = document.querySelector('.pic.active');
  const activeIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(pics, activePic);
  const nextIndex = activeIndex === lastPic ? 0 : activeIndex + 1;
  const nextPic = pics[nextIndex];

  setTimeout(() => activePic.classList.remove('active'), transitionDelay);
  setTimeout(() => nextPic.classList.add('active'), totalDelay);
}

setInterval(toggleClass, intervalDelay);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 800ms ease; /* immediately start fading out when active class is lost */
}
.pic.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="pic active" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%201" alt="">
  <img class="pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%202" alt="">
  <img class="pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%203" alt="">
  <img class="pic" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%204" alt="">
</div>
```

## Keyframes method

I won't go into full detail here, but it would probably look something like this:

```
@keyframes pulse1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse4 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Note that we don't even toggle the `z-index` because there's no point: only one of them is ever visible at a time. Just position them all on top of each other from the start, and their `z-index` won't matter.

(I don't think the `z-index` portion of the animation you have in your question is even doing anything because `z-index` isn't animatable.)

Comment: Hi, I copy-pasted the JS solution in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trd1vwps/2/). I have one quick question. I am wondering if there is any way, we can place `active` class
wrapper class. At this moment, I can see it is with img tag.

Comment: The reason why I am asking to do that because I am not sure how many images would be inside  div as the images inside the div is controlled through admin section.

Comment: @flash you could certainly do that. The JS wouldn't need to be modified conceptually at all, just change the classes to whatever suits your need. In your case, maybe instead of `document.querySelectorAll('.pic')` you would have `document.querySelectorAll('.featured-block__item')` and instead of `active` you would use `featured-block__item-active`.

Comment: @flash one problem you are gonna have here that I didn't notice until just now is that your images are all wrapped in links. Well things with `opacity: 0` are still clickable, so with this approach basically whatever the last link in the HTML is would be on top, and that would be the link that always gets clicked since we are not toggling z-index. To fix that you may need to just also add `z-index: 1` to the active class, in addition to `opacity: 1`. It wouldn't need to be transitioned; just once logo A fades out, logo B's link becomes clickable even as it is still busy fading in.

Comment: Hey, sorry I got busy with some work. I have some questions.  

**Question 1**: transitionDuration => I am wondering what is `transitionDuration` above ? Is it the delay (white flash which we see) which happens on moving from one image to another ?

**Question 2**: transitionDelay =>  Is it the presenation time of an image ? Meaning the time span for which the image stay at their place ? 

**Question 3**: totalDelay => Is it only for one image ?

Comment: @flash Yes, that's all correct. You should be able to modify `transitionDuration` and `transitionDelay` to get the exact timing you want in the animation; the other variables are computed from those, so you don't need to do anything. Note that `transitionDuration` in the JS matches the `transition-duration` CSS property on the image. (We're using the `transition` shorthand here, which includes `transition-duration`.) Play around with it and see what you think.

Comment: Thanks. I am marking as accept. I have one more question on the basis of this question. Initially I thought, I should write it here but it would be a lot of words so I will post another question.

Comment: Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57558793/how-to-add-a-class-in-js-on-the-basis-of-json). Its very similar to this question.

Comment: I am summarizing my question here in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkn672sg/). My apologies for summarizing in the fiddle. Its quite a dirty way.

Comment: @flash I will take a look and answer/comment on the other question if I can help. (Looks like you already have an answer. Not sure if it's right or not; haven't dug into it yet.)

Comment: Its already have an answer but I think he didn't understand my question. Are you able to get my question ? Let know if you need more information.