# How to hide html tag content in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, hide

I have a DOM as shown below in which I want to hide **specific h2 tag contents**.

All of them have the same class **shows-list__title**.  The contents are at 
**Line A (Vote 2015 Phone-in)**, **Line B(Vote 2015 Phone-in)** and 
**Line C (Vote 2015 Special)**.

```
<li class="shows-list__letter">
    <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title">V</h1>
    <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://sandbox.cpac.ca/en/programs/vote-2015-debates/">
        <h2 class="shows-list__title">Vote 2015 Debates</h2> <!-- Line A -->
    </a>
</li>
<li class="shows-list__letter">
    <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://sandbox.cpac.ca/en/programs/vote-2015-phone-in/">
        <h2 class="shows-list__title">Vote 2015 Phone-in</h2> <!-- Line B -->
    </a>
</li>
<li class="shows-list__letter">
    <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://sandbox.cpac.ca/en/programs/vote-2015-special/">
        <h2 class="shows-list__title">Vote 2015 Special</h2> <!-- Line C -->
    </a>
</li>
<li class="shows-list__letter">
    <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://sandbox.cpac.ca/en/programs/voting-reform/">
        <h2 class="shows-list__title">Voting Reform</h2>
    </a>
</li>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what JS code I need to add so that it hides **Vote 2015 Debates** , **Vote 2015 Phone-in** and **Vote 2015 Special** from the DOM/webpage. I don't want to hide that h2 tag which has content **Voting Reform**.

Comment: Try this:
`var elementList = document.querySelectorAll("h2"); elementList.forEach((element) => {element.style = "display: none;";});`

Comment: Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to fetch all the clalss name with `shows-list__title`. And iterate the returned node list with either css or html hidden attribute

Comment: @ Peter Warrington but in the dom there are many h2 tags. I want to hide the h2 tags which have the content `Vote 2015 Debates`, `Vote 2015 Phone-in` and `Vote 2015 Special`.

Comment: @flash
replace "h2" with ".shows-list__title"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can `forEach` elements and add hidden for visibility `css` attribute

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll("h2.shows-list__title")


const ext = ["Vote 2015 Debates", "Vote 2015 Phone-in", "Vote 2015 Special"];

el.forEach(el =>
  ext.includes(el.innerText) &&
  el.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;")
)
```

```html
<li class="shows-list__letter">
  <h1 class="shows-list__letter-title">V</h1>
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://sandbox.cpac.ca/en/programs/vote-2015-debates/">
    <h2 class="shows-list__title">Vote 2015 Debates</h2>
    <!-- Line A -->
  </a>
</li>
<li class="shows-list__letter">
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://sandbox.cpac.ca/en/programs/vote-2015-phone-in/">
    <h2 class="shows-list__title">Vote 2015 Phone-in</h2>
    <!-- Line B -->
  </a>
</li>
<li class="shows-list__letter">
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://sandbox.cpac.ca/en/programs/vote-2015-special/">
    <h2 class="shows-list__title">Vote 2015 Special</h2>
    <!-- Line C -->
  </a>
</li>
<li class="shows-list__letter">
  <a class="shows-list__link" href="http://sandbox.cpac.ca/en/programs/vote-2015-special/">
    <h2 class="shows-list__title">Voting Reform</h2>
    <!-- Line D -->
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I have modified my question in order to give more information.

Comment: I don't want to hide that h2 tag which has content **Voting Reform**.

Comment: that's better for you having an array for words that you want to hide :) better than a long condition with multiple `||`

Comment: I have posted one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481429/how-to-use-keyframes-for-cross-fade-gallery-of-images-in-css?noredirect=1#comment101446555_57481429) a day ago but I haven't received much attention. I am wondering if you can have a look. Just wondering if the solution is possible via Javascript ?

Answer (score 3):

So you are looking for these exact textual matches that can be done like so

```
let toHide = ["Vote 2015 Debates", "Vote 2015 Phone-in", "Vote 2015 Special"];
document.querySelectorAll("h2.shows-list__title").forEach(elm => elm.setAttribute("style",toHide.includes(elm.innerText)?"display:none;":""));
```

Please note this is a quick and dirty JS only hacky way of doing this, I would say you should add a specific class on them in HTML and add CSS that hides that class for the best performance.

With thanks to @G.Aziz for the improvement of using an array

Oh hell, I got thinking about it and here is a completely unreadable golfed version saving your bandwidth a whopping 46 bytes per page request!!! Don't use this it's just for fun to show how small you could make this if you had your example as `Vote 2016` this would hide them aswell.

```
let h=["Debates", "Phone-in", "Special"];document.querySelectorAll("h2.shows-list__title").forEach(e=> e.setAttribute("style",h.includes(e.innerText.split(' ')[2])?"display:none;":""));
```

Comment: In the dom there are many h2 tags. I want to hide the h2 tags which have the content Vote 2015 Debates, Vote 2015 Phone-in and Vote 2015 Special.

Comment: I don't want to hide that h2 tag which content **Voting Reform**.

Comment: Updated for you

Comment: check mine and update yours with an array of words to hide :)

Comment: @G.aziz thanks, done that it's like were golfing this away :D

Comment: I have posted one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481429/how-to-use-keyframes-for-cross-fade-gallery-of-images-in-css?noredirect=1#comment101446555_57481429) a day ago but I haven't received much attention. I am wondering if you can have a look. Just wondering if the solution is possible via Javascript ?