# How to add a class in JS on the basis of JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

**File.php**

I have a html/php code as shown below. The following code is inside **File.php** file.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <?php if (in_array("1", $data->toggle_multi_tiles)) {
  <img class="featured-block__item featured-block__item-active" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%201" alt="">
  <?php } <?php if (in_array("2", $data->toggle_multi_tiles)) { ?>
  <img class="featured-block__item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%202" alt="">
  <?php } if (in_array("3", $data->toggle_multi_tiles)) { ?> 
  <img class="featured-block__item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%203" alt="">
  <?php }  ?>
</div>
```

**Admin.php**

I have a JSON (Line A) as shown below. The following php code is inside **Admin.php** file.

```
{"toggle_multi_tiles":["1","2","3"]}  // Line A
```

**file.php** and **admin.php** files are communicating with each other.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the JS code below so that it adds `featured-block__item-active` class in DOM on the basis of JSON something like this:

When its => `{"toggle_multi_tiles":["1","2","3"]}` then DOM should be like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="featured-block__item featured-block__item-active" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%201" alt="">  <!-- 1 -->
  <img class="featured-block__item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%202" alt="">          <!-- 2 -->  
  <img class="featured-block__item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%203" alt="">          <!-- 3 -->
</div>
```

When its => `{"toggle_multi_tiles":["1","2"]}` then DOM should be like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="featured-block__item featured-block__item-active" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%201" alt="">  <!-- 1 -->
  <img class="featured-block__item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%202" alt="">          <!-- 2 -->  
</div>
```

When its => `{"toggle_multi_tiles":["1","3"]}` then DOM should be like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="featured-block__item featured-block__item-active" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%201" alt="">  <!-- 1 -->
  <img class="featured-block__item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%203" alt="">          <!-- 3 -->
</div>
```

When its => `{"toggle_multi_tiles":["2","3"]}` then DOM should be like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="featured-block__item featured-block__item-active" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%202" alt="">  <!-- 2 -->  
  <img class="featured-block__item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%203" alt="">          <!-- 3 -->
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const pics = document.querySelectorAll('.multi-tiles .featured-block__item');
const lastPic = pics.length - 1;
const transitionDuration = 800; // matches CSS
const transitionDelay = 3000; // up to you
const totalDelay = transitionDuration + transitionDelay;
const intervalDelay = (transitionDuration * 2) + transitionDelay; // time to fade out + time to fade in + time to stay featured-block__item-featured-block__item-active

function toggleClass() {
  const activePic = document.querySelector('.featured-block__item.featured-block__item-featured-block__item-active');
  const activeIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(pics, activePic);
  const nextIndex = activeIndex === lastPic ? 0 : activeIndex + 1;
  const nextPic = pics[nextIndex];

  setTimeout(() => activePic.classList.remove('featured-block__item-featured-block__item-active'), transitionDelay);
  setTimeout(() => nextPic.classList.add('featured-block__item-featured-block__item-active'), totalDelay);
}

setInterval(toggleClass, intervalDelay);
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you want to happen here. My understanding was that you would render the HTML one time (and if it comes from a PHP template, so be it, that's not specifically relevant) and then simply use JS to toggle a class on the images. There is no need to be adding/removing images from the DOM once the slideshow is there. What is the ultimate goal here? The answer posted here already does indeed produce the HTML you want, but I suspect that isn't what you're after. All that answer does is write HTML to the DOM, but you're doing that in PHP.

Comment: What is happening right now is, let say the JSON is `{"toggle_multi_tiles":["2","3"]}` then the DOM is like this as shown below in the DOM **(pasted below)**. Whats wrong with this when the animation 
starts then for the few seconds its blank because there is no 1st image. 
`<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="featured-block__item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%202" alt="">  <!-- Image 2 -->
  <img class="featured-block__item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%203" alt="">  <!-- Image 3 -->
</div>`

Comment: The fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/xLoqud8m

Comment: We are always treating 1st image as an active class. But there is a chance there is no 1st image sometimes.

Comment: It can start from Image 2 and Image 3.

Comment: In that case all you need to do is just find the first picture and apply the active class on page load, and then your JS function (my answer from the other question) can proceed as normal, nothing extra required. The active class doesn't have to be included in the HTML from the start; I just did that as a simplification because you didn't explain that it was a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
const admin = {"toggle_multi_tiles":["1","3","2"]};
const toggle = admin.toggle_multi_tiles;
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
let html = [];

for (let i=0;i<toggle.length; i++) {
  html.push(`<img class="featured-block__item${i===0?" featured-block__item-active":""}" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=picture%20${toggle[i]}" alt="">  <!-- ${toggle[i]} -->`)
}
wrapper.innerHTML=html.join("\n")
```

```css
.featured-block__item-active { border:3px solid red }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: This question is very similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481429/how-to-use-keyframes-for-cross-fade-gallery-of-images-in-css/57501667?noredirect=1#comment101580888_57501667).

Comment: I have explained in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkn672sg/) what changes I need to make in that question. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What is your aim here? I answered your question as asked here. If it is the same as another question you asked, I’ll close this as a duplicate - if not what is missing from my answer?

Comment: I am just giving more information. Both questions are different.

Comment: So did I answer your question or am I supposed to do something with the extra information? I am confused

Comment: You did answer my question. I am having a look. I will let you know.